# Unable to build libharu on windows

Tags: c++, windows, build, libraries, libharu

I've been trying all day to find a way to use the libharu library on windows with c++, but I can't figure out how to build it...

I've tried `nmake -f script/Makefile.msvc` but this gives me:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.31.31107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -Fosrc\hpdf_utils.obj -MT -nologo -O2 -Iinclude -Iwin32\include -I"../../libpng"\include -I"../../zlib"\include -c src\hpdf_utils.c
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

I also tried using vcpkg but I get an error saying it cannot find visual studio. I put a `VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH` variable pointing to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE` and it still can't find a valid visual studio instance.

Since my c++ project is compiled with mingw I tried using mysys and ran the `buildconf.sh` file to make a configure file which I then ran with `./configure` within mysys and I get

```
checking Zlib install prefix... configure: error: Unable to locate Zlib headers, please use --with-zlib=<DIR>
```

I'm kind of tired of working on this thing and I need to be able to use this library. I don't really know how I can install zlib on mysys or whatever this problem is. I know on Linux it would be easier but I need to compile this for windows. Did anyone ever successfully build libharu on windows and if yes how did you do it?

Looking forward to any help I can get.

Comment: For that `nmake` command to succeed, trying running that command from Visual Studio command prompt. Basically, it's unable to find the VC++ compiler

Comment: Have you used `vcvarsall.bat` to set up terminal configuration yet?

Comment: Sorry for late replies.. I've had very busy last few days. How would I se vcvarsall.bat? And is the visual studio command prompt the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

nmake uses a different syntax than the Unix makefiles; try to compile it with Visual Studio and cmake to generate the solution.

In addition, run it in Visual Studio's command prompt (`%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`)

I was able to compile libharu without errors with theese commands (in the directory of the repo):

```
cmake -S . -O out
cmake --build out
```

After that, I found the build in the folder, ".\out\src\Debug".